# How to get increment value of every marked cell by one in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spread sheet with numbers spread around several columns and rows.
I would like to be able to select several cells in the spreadsheet and increment the value for every cell by 1.

I already created a button that calls a function in scripts. I am also able to get my ranges like this:

```
var sel = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
```

I am able to loop through my ranges, but I cannot get the value of each individual cell and increase it's value. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

[`getRanges()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#getRanges()) is a function that returns a list of ranges. In order to increment all the values, you have to:

1. Iterate over the ranges
2. Iterate over every cell in the range, using either `getCell()` or `getValues()` (which is faster).

You can see a code example on how to do it using `getValues()`:

```js
var sel = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
  var range = sel[i];
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var j=0; j<values.length; j++) {
    for (var k=0; k<values[0].length; k++) {
      values[j][k] += 1;
    }
  }
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop that goes through the ranges, you can simply get the current value in the cell and set the value again + 1. This is the most basic way to do it but may not be the optimal way.

```
  for(var i in sel){
    var range = sel[i].getValue();
    sel[i].setValue(range + 1);
  }
```